# Slow sql queries between docker containers on Rancher1.6

Tags: mysql, performance, docker, networking, rancher

I have a container running a Flask server and a container running a MySQL server with a service link in the same stack on the same host.

The Flask server need to run subprocesses, which read data (>100MB) from database and I use `pandas.read_sql` to do that, but it seems that the networking between the containers becomes the bottleneck. The speed of a single thread is only about 500kbps as I saw in the rancher web interface.

[image]

I run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and found that the database spent large amount of time "sending data". The queries are fast. Maybe I need to do some configurations.

Though I guess it's a networking issue, I can provide further information about other aspects if needed.

Comment: I'm not particularly sure why you ask this question on a programming Q/A site, as opposed to a sysadmin one.

Comment: Where is the host running? If both the containers are running on the same host you definitely should getting higher speeds than what you mentioned. Is the host busy doing something else? Do a tcpdump inside the flask container, may be that will give you a clue.